# Using row() in jooq to map result into custom seekStep class

Tags: java, jooq

Since I don't want to use RecordX class (in my case I am returning 11 fields from query) I've created custom mapper to map SelectSeekStep result into it. The problem occurs when I have fields that are part of joined table. E.g.

```
@Value
public class CustomMapperSelectSeekStep {
  private final String field1;
  private final String field2;
  private final String field3;
  private final String field4;
  private final String field5;
  private final String field6;
  private final String field7;
  private final String test_id;
  private final String field9;
  private final String field10;
}
```

Let's say that all fields except `test_id` fields are part of main table (let's call it `dummy`) and that field is part of `test` table which we will connect with `left join`.

```
dslContext
.select(
row(DUMMY.FIELD1,
    DUMMY.FIELD2,
    DUMMY.FIELD3,
    DUMMY.FIELD4,
    DUMMY.FIELD5,
    DUMMY.FIELD6,
    DUMMY.FIELD7,
    TEST.TEST_NAME,
    DUMMY.FIELD8,
    DUMMY.FIELD9,
    DUMMY.FIELD10).mapping(CustomMapperSelectSeekStep::new))
.from(DUMMY)
.leftJoin(TEST).on(TEST.ID.eq(DUMMY.TEST_ID))
.orderBy(DUMMY.FIELD1);
```

Exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field ("test"."test_name") is not contained in Row 
(row (
"DUMMY"."FIELD1",
"DUMMY"."FIELD2",
"DUMMY"."FIELD3",
"DUMMY"."FIELD4",
"DUMMY"."FIELD5",
"DUMMY"."FIELD6",
"DUMMY"."FIELD7",
"DUMMY"."FIELD8",
"TEST"."TEST_NAME",
"DUMMY"."FIELD9",
"DUMMY"."FIELD10"
))
```

UPDATE: added entire method call:

```
dslContext.transaction(configuration -> {
DSLContext localDsl = DSL.using(configuration);
try (Cursor<Record1<CustomMapperSelectSeekStep>> records = 
selectRecords(localDsl)
    .fetchSize(1000)
    .resultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY)
    .resultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
    .fetchLazy()) {
        processRecords(records);
    }
});
//method
private SelectSeekStep1<Record1<CustomMapperSelectSeekStep>,Timestamp> selectRecords(DSLContext dslContext) {
return dslContext.select(
    row(DUMMY.FIELD1,
        DUMMY.FIELD2,
        DUMMY.FIELD3,
        DUMMY.FIELD4,
        DUMMY.FIELD5,
        DUMMY.FIELD6,
        DUMMY.FIELD7,
        TEST.TEST_NAME,
        DUMMY.FIELD8,
        DUMMY.FIELD9,
        DUMMY.FIELD10).mapping(CustomMapperSelectSeekStep::new))
    .from(DUMMY)
    .leftJoin(TEST).on(TEST.ID.eq(DUMMY.TEST_ID))
    .orderBy(DUMMY.FIELD1);
    }
```

Inside process record I am mapping `Record` objects to desired object type.

```
void processRecords(List<Records> records) {
record.map(recordMapper);
}
```

I have custom recordMapper implementation where i am doing logic like this:

```
testName = record.get(TEST.TEST_NAME, Test.class);
```

Stack trace:

```
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.indexFail(Tools.java:1769)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:331)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:336)
at org.test.CustomMapper.map(CustomMapper.java:42)
at org.test.CustomMapper.map(CustomMapper.java:16)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.map(AbstractRecord.java:904)
at org.test.Processor.processRecords(Processor.java:88)
at org.test.Repository.lambda$fetchLazy$0(Repository.java:78)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.lambda$transaction$5(DefaultDSLContext.java:611)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.lambda$transactionResult0$3(DefaultDSLContext.java:549)
```

Comment: 1) What jOOQ version are you using? 2) What's the full stack trace (at least the relevant bits), 3) How did you execute this query?

Comment: 1) <jooq.version>3.15.4</jooq.version>
2) 
 at org.jooq.impl.Tools.indexFail(Tools.java:1769)
 at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:331)
 at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:336)
3) query is executed inside transaction, using fetchLazy()

Comment: Can you please update your question with the details? Including the exact code *you* wrote to help reproduce it. I don't think I could reproduce the problem from the information you've given so far.

Comment: added UPDATE section with entire method call

Comment: And what does `processRecords` do? Does the error happen in there, or inside of `fetchLazy()`? (I can't see it, which is why I asked for the complete stack trace)

Comment: I've updated question. As it seems problem lays in my custom mapper, I'm not sure what is the correct way of mapping row data received inside record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've nested your record to have a type like this

```java
Cursor<Record1<CustomMapperSelectSeekStep>>
```

When you thought you had a type like this:

```java
Cursor<Record10<T1, T2, ..., T10>>
```

In the latter case, you could simply extract the projected column like you did:

```java
record.get(TEST.TEST_NAME);
```

But when you have a nested record, that column no longer exists, it's nested in an anonymous `Record1<?>` type. Not only that, but because you used an [ad-hoc converter using `convertFrom()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), there's no nested record anymore, but jOOQ projected your custom POJO type `CustomMapperSelectSeekStep` for you.

So, just read your value like this:

```java
void processRecords(List<Record1<CustomMapperSelectSeekStep>> records) {
    for (Record1<CustomMapperSelectSeekStep> record : records) {
        CustomMapperSelectSeekStep pojo : record.value1();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that `record.value1()` solved my issue